# How to download the lambda package from a repository (instead of s3 or local directory) and deploy it using terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I can download the package using `null_resource` (curl command). But the download happens only when we do `terraform apply`. I need to download the package during `terraform plan` also so that correct source_code_hash can be used and the package can be uploaded if there is any change in the source code.

Is there any way we can download the package from artifactory during `plan` also?

Or if we could always update the lambda deployment package?

Comment: Can't you just set publish to true? That way if there is a change you will get a new Lambda version?

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting your terraform pipeline into build, release pipeline. Build pipeline would generate the artifact and you can upload the build artifact to some artifact repository while release pipeline would download that artifact and run terraform `init/plan/apply` on it.
Below are sample Azure DevOps tasks to build, publish Lambdas:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1



- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Lambdas'
  inputs:
  projects: '**/*.Lambda/*.csproj'
  arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish Lambdas
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.Lambda/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```